# How to visualize the world while travelling near the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, visualization

I have been having some trouble with this for a while. I think in terms of vivid , moving images and i haven't been able to visualize this completely. I wondered if a person, like the Flash from the comics, who is moving near the speed of light, how would his/her perception of reality change. Also, how would their cognitive speeds have to change to process that magnitude of information.

Also, if anybody has any kind of math that they could refer me to, that would be splendid.

Comment: Several computer simulations here: http://www.spacetimetravel.org

Comment: Hi  I don't think your speed of cognition is a physics question, more a biology area imo   regards

Comment: Also MIT came out with a game called A Slower Speed of Light. As you collect orbs, you travel faster and faster and the game simulates the perception differences. There are some gameplay videos on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=slower+speed+of+light) that should be helpful.

Comment: [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation) might be relevant here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cognitive abilities while traveling relativistically and not really about physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main effect that would be affecting how this man would see is the contraction of length that are not in its referential(travelling with him). 
If a referential is moving at the speed v close to c in the +x direction. Then every object that are not in its referential will be shorten along the x axis by a factor $\gamma$ such that :

$L_{x,Flash}=L_{x,real}.\frac{1}{\gamma}$   with $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^{2}}} $

So if Falsh is going at 0.6c a stick that measures 1 meter along the x axis would actually appear to be 80cm long for Flash!